# Does C# Task required any thread?

Tags: c#, .net

I was just searching the answer that whether a Task required any thread or not but did not find any clear answer. Could anybody please provide the answer or provide a link

That will clear that whether:

1. Task runs on current thread
2. Task create a new thread
3. Task use a new thread from thread pool

Comment: Just look it up http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Task can be ran in current thread, new thread, threadpool thread or no thread at all. To answer your question, it would take several pages. Please read on..

Comment: A Task is, as the name indicate, an abstraction around a task. That is, a defined unit of work. Whether this unit of work executes on the same thread or another depends entirely on the way you run the task

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx has everything you need to know (probably).

Comment: To add to all the links in the comments, here is one more - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx - the first paragraph in the remarks section directly answers you question IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was just searching the answer that whether a Task required any
>   thread

The answer is: *it depends*. On what does it depend? On which kind of `Task` you're creating (or consuming). It can be any of the three you mentioned.

Let's break it down via an example:

First, no threads:

```
public Task FooAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(false); 
}
```

Invoking this method call would cause no thread to be created. Also, many of the async IO API's exposed by the BCL also cause no threads to be used while invoking the asynchronous operation.

Second, threadpool thread:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => /* Massive work here*/);
}
```

This example would cause a delegate to be invoked on a threadpool thread.

Third, cause a new thread to be created:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => Console.WriteLine("Foo"),
                                     CancellationToken.None,
                                     TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

As you see, a `Task` is an abstraction to a unit of work which will complete in the future. You can have it in any of those three ways, depends on what you're actually doing an on the code execution.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - it's an abstraction layer on top of the thread pool to support easier async programming.

From MSDN:

> the work performed by a Task object typically executes asynchronously
>   on a thread pool thread rather than synchronously on the main
>   application thread

For further depth:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx